# Unable to connect to MYSQL container with sequel pro client

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelpro

i am a newbie to docker and have bee struggling to connect to the docker container with sequel pro. I downloaded the image `docker pull mysql/mysql-server:latest`. And executed the command to run a container:

`docker run --name mysql-server -v /User/path/data:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql/mysql-server:latest`.

Now i am attempting to connect mysql client i.e sequel pro to the docker container that runs mysql but i get the following response below:
[image]

I followed tutorials on youtube and also documentation from docker but i do not know why i keep getting this.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced the same problem.

Running: `$ docker ps`

Gave the [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw5HA.png):
`PORTS 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp mysql-server`

Which told me [to use '0.0.0.0' as host IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fofjq.png).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here: `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSSWORD=root` in `SSS`. Just remove one of `S`

Comment: i did fix the typo but still getting the same error

Comment: try run mysql without mounting volumes. Run  docker `docker run --name mysql-server -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql/mysql-server:latest`

Comment: i tried running the command you provided without mounting the volume and still cannot connect getting the same error